# unit tests don't seem to allow parallel.foreach to execute in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, parallel-processing, xunit.net

I have a C# unit test (in actuality more an integration test) that tests a block of code that includes a `Parallel.ForEach` loop.  When this code runs in debug mode, locally or in a deployed environment, the parallelism works as expected (completes in about 20 seconds).  However, when my integration tests hit that piece of code, they eventually time out (taking over 4 minutes).  My guess is that somehow the parallel nature is being turned off when the unit tests run.  I know it isn't a hardware situation, because the same machine can execute parallelism while debugging and be slow while running unit tests.  However, I don't know what setting or configuration of the unit tests would cause this.

Note that this is not an issue with running tests in parallel - due to other constraints, we must run tests in serial.  This is within a single test, the performance of `Parallel.ForEach`, on the same machine, the same block of code, performs wildly differently if it is run while debugging (via IIS localhost) or running a unit test.

Our unit testing framework is xUnit.  We use TypeMock for a verity of mocks around static calls, but we have not configured anything that should inhibit threading.  The unit tests show that there are 32K+ threads available in the pool.  I can have a separate unit test that shows it can run things in parallel.

**The Unit Test**

```
[Fact]
public void AssertManyAssetsEnumerated()
{
    var args = new EnumerateArgs();
    args.FirstIndex = 0;
    args.LastIndex = 22263;
    args.FileName = LARGE_INDEX_ASSET_PREFIX;
    args.FullLibrarySearch = true;

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    var translators = new FilenameFieldTranslator();

    stopwatch.Restart();
    var assets = Services.AssetService.Enumerate(ScenarioBuilder.MasterAdminUser, args, translators);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Assert.Equal(22263, assets.Count);

    var assetIDs = assets.Select(a => a.ID);
    Assert.Equal(assetIDs.Distinct(), assetIDs);

    var assetFileNames = assets.Select(a => a.FileName);
    Assert.Equal(assetFileNames.Distinct(), assetFileNames);

    Assert.Equal(PrependZerosAndCreateFileName(lower + 1), assets[0].FileName);
    Assert.Equal(PrependZerosAndCreateFileName(realUpper), assets.Last().FileName);

    //All asserts up to this point pass, only this time assertion fails
    var start = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    var maxTimespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);
    Assert.InRange(stopwatch.Elapsed, start, maxTimespan);
}
```

**The Loop**

```
public SearchResult RunSearch(IUser user, AssetCollection collection, Aggregations aggregations, FieldTranslators translators)
{
    if (!collection.IsLargeRequest)
    {
        return RunSingleSearch(user, collection, aggregations, translators);
    }

    var subquerySize = 1000;

    var subqueryCollections = new List<AssetCollection>();
    for (var i = collection.FirstIndex; i < collection.LastIndex; i += subquerySize)
    {
        var subqueryCollection = Clone(collection);
        subqueryCollection.FirstIndex = i;
        subqueryCollection.LastIndex = i + subquerySize;

        subqueryCollections.Add(subqueryCollection);
    }

    var results = new List<SearchResult>();
    var resultLock = new object();

    Parallel.ForEach(subqueryCollections, c =>
    {
        var result = RunSingleSearch(user, c, aggregations, translators);

        lock (resultLock)
        {
            results.Add(result);
        }
    });

    var overallResult = CombineResults(collection, results);

    return overallResult;
}
```

Again, on the same machine, I can run this code in the web app and it executes within 20 seconds for that request.  Do the same request in a unit test, on the same machine, the same code,  and it takes 4 minutes.  I have run into lots of dead ends regarding what might be making it slow, but I just don't know.

- We have parallel execution disabled in our xUnit test suite, as TypeMock Isolator doesn't like it (at least the way we use it).  I tried enabling it again, but it did not fix the performance issues in the unit test
- As mentioned earlier, we use TypeMock Isolator to mock certain static calls.  We have not done anything (that I see) that would limit/change how parallel execution would work regarding threading and/or tasks.
- The threadpool in the unit tests has 32K+ threads available.
- Separate unit tests can confirm that a different `Parallel.ForEach` loop can indeed execute in parallel (looks to be about 10 threads at once on the machine I have been using)
- We are running the unit tests in Visual Studio 2017, using the most recent version of the xUnit visual studio runner (2.4.0)

Any help or recommendations of things to investigate will be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend using xUnit to write unit tests and only unit tests, and not using xUnit to write integration tests.  Commingling integration tests with unit tests will not end well.  They should be kept separate.  Integration tests and unit tests have very different characteristics, for example:  integration tests almost always can only be run in serial, unit tests should always be able to be run in parallel.

Comment: @Eljay I certainly agree.  However, this is a legacy project that has many contraints.  We are working to have genuine unit tests in our solution, and to separate those from integration - but as of right now, that isn't an option.

Comment: @ODawgG - since lists in and of themselves aren't threadsafe, the lock ensures that all collections get added correctly to the list.  For instance, if my request is sized at 1M, and it has to make 1000 subqueries, then there are sometimes 1 or 2 results that don't get added due to threading conflicts.